# mongod --dbpath /Users/rahul/data/db command not working

Tags: mongodb

I installed MongoDB on my PC. It was working perfectly, but suddenly it stopped working.
When I try to `sudo mongod --dbpath /Users/rahul/data/db` I get this:

```
(base) rahul@Rahuls-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo mongod --dbpath /Users/rahul/data/db
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.328+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.334+06:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.334+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.334+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":906,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/Users/rahul/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Rahuls-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.334+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.3","gitVersion":"913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.334+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.334+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/Users/rahul/data/db"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-12T10:59:37.336+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit code 48 means the port is already in use, Check for any running mongod process and stop it to free the port.

And it is mentioned in the error log you posted
{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}

Comment: MongoDB compass was running then